# My C program only shows zeroes in output despite my code being correct

Tags: c, codeblocks

My code is correct I guess. Howevwe, for the pay slip, the output only shows zeroes and does not give the right output. I'm compiling in code blocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float bs, hra, ma, da, ta, tax, ub, totalsalary;
    printf("Enter basic salary: \n");
    scanf("%f", &bs);
    if (bs < 15000)
    {hra == 0.03 * bs && ma == 0.02 * bs && da == 0.02 * bs && ta == 0.01 * bs && tax == 0.005 * bs && ub == 0.04 * bs;}
    else if (bs >= 15000 && bs <= 30000)
    {hra == 0.05 * bs && ma == 0.03 * bs && da == 0.04 * bs && ta == 0.02 * bs && tax == 0.02 * bs && ub == 0.04 * bs;}
    else
     {hra == 0.04 * bs && ma == 0.07 * bs && da == 0.03 * bs && ta == 0.03 * bs && tax == 0.03 * bs && ub == 0.1 * bs;}

    totalsalary == (float) bs + hra + ma + da + ta - tax - ub;
    printf("\nSalary slip\n");
    printf("House rent allowance: %.2f\n", hra);
    printf("Medical Allowance: %.2f\n", ma);
    printf("Daily Allowance: %.2f\n", da);
    printf("Traveling Allowance: %.2f\n", ta);
    printf("Tax:  %.2f\n", tax);
    printf("Utility bills: %.2f\n", ub);
    printf("Total Salary is: %.2f\n", totalsalary);
    return 0;
}
```

[This is my output screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSrBF.png)

I've even searched for codes in chat gpt and if i copy and paste from there, it works. Mut the code i've written doesn't. The code that chat gpt gave and the one written by me is exactly the same.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Output is text. Post text as properly formatted text.$

Comment: Err.... _"My C program only shows zeroes in output despite my code being correct"_ well obviously your code is not correct, otherwise you wouldn't be asking a question.

Comment: ChatGPT can easily produce incorrect code. So if you simply copy/paste from there, you are at your own risk. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: ChatGPT is for generating _lies_, not for generating source code.

Comment: Fatima Ismail, for _money_, do not use `float`.  `double` is better.  Yet even `double` has issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the original post is not really correct.

A piece of code like `hra == 0.03 * bs && ma == 0.02 * bs && da == 0.02 * bs && ta == 0.01 * bs && tax == 0.005 * bs && ub == 0.04 * bs;` only checks whether certain things are equal; it doesn't change the value of any variable.
To actually change all the relevant variables, use `=` instead of `==` and `;` instead of `&&`.

Similarly, the `==` in your `totalsalary == (float) bs + hra + ma + da + ta - tax - ub;` should really be `=`.

And since your variables are already float, there is no need to use `(float)`.

The following should work (but need to be formatted better).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float bs, hra, ma, da, ta, tax, ub, totalsalary;
    printf("Enter basic salary: \n");
    scanf("%f", &bs);
    if (bs < 15000)
    {hra=0.03 * bs ; ma=0.02 * bs ; da=0.02 * bs ; ta=0.01 * bs ; tax=0.005 * bs ; ub=0.04 * bs;}
    else if (bs >= 15000 && bs <= 30000)
    {hra=0.05 * bs ; ma=0.03 * bs ; da=0.04 * bs ; ta=0.02 * bs ; tax=0.02 * bs ; ub=0.04 * bs;}
    else
     {hra=0.04 * bs ; ma=0.07 * bs ; da=0.03 * bs ; ta=0.03 * bs ; tax=0.03 * bs ; ub=0.1 * bs;}

    totalsalary= bs + hra + ma + da + ta - tax - ub;
    printf("\nSalary slip\n");
    printf("House rent allowance: %.2f\n", hra);
    printf("Medical Allowance: %.2f\n", ma);
    printf("Daily Allowance: %.2f\n", da);
    printf("Traveling Allowance: %.2f\n", ta);
    printf("Tax:  %.2f\n", tax);
    printf("Utility bills: %.2f\n", ub);
    printf("Total Salary is: %.2f\n", totalsalary);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you are using the correct use of brackets. for e.g this

`if (bs >= 15000 && bs <= 30000)` could be written as `if ((bs >= 15000) && (bs <= 30000))`

like this

`{hra == 0.03 * bs && ma == 0.02 * bs && da == 0.02 * bs && ta == 0.01 * bs && tax == 0.005 * bs && ub == 0.04 * bs;}` coule be

{(hra == 0.03 * bs) && (ma == 0.02 * bs) && (da == 0.02 * bs) && (ta == 0.01 * bs) && (tax == 0.005 * bs) && (ub == 0.04 * bs);}

Also, you are comparing the values of hra , ma , da, ta , tax and ub and not assigning to them.

may be you wanted to write

```
if (bs < 15000)
{
  hra = 0.03 * bs;
  ma = 0.02 * bs;
  da = 0.02 * bs;
  ta = 0.01 * bs;
  tax = 0.005 * bs;
  ub == 0.04 * bs;
}
```

Correct the program and see the values coming in.

Few suggestions:

- Please dont use chatgpt in initial phase of your learning, learn by yourself and understand the basics before using chatGPT.
- Use varibale after assigning values to them, for e.g. use totalsalary = 0.0f
- Welcome to progrmaming world

Comment: The parentheses you added aren't necessary.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I hadn't used chatgpt initially. I did write the code by myself but it wasn't working so i just wanted to make sure mine was correct or not! Thank you for your help, the code is working now!